# TeXworks: How to store spell checker settings?

Tags: spelling, ide, texworks

I'm using TeXworks to write my documents. TeXworks provides the ability to spell check the document, chosing a specific language (english, german or french in my case).

But I noticed that every time i restart TeXworks the spell checker is switched off and I have to enable it again and also chose the language again.

How can I store that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually do this in the »Preferences« dialogue on the »Editor« tab (see attachment). I'm not aware of another solution.

---

[image]

Comment: So easy and nevertheless I dind't found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can also specify the spelling language on a per file basis:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = <language_code>
```

e.g.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
```