# TexWorks (coming with MiKTeX) does not underline misspelled words

Tags: texworks, spell

`TexWorks` (Windows 10, `MiKTeX` latest version, fully updated) does not underline misspelled words. This worked fine until a few days ago.

The dictionary files can be found in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\hunspell\dicts`. I did check en_US in the menu.

Comment: There are quite a few previous questions on this top (search for "texworks spell check"); this one looks interesting: [TeXworks: How to store spell checker settings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10231)

Comment: I checked the Preferences, they look right. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but for others to see ...

Try zooming in on the script window. The red underlines won't appear when the texts are too small, at least in my environment.

Comment: The problem I had was fixed eventually by the developer.